# np.arange giving unxexpected value

Tags: python

I am using np.arange to generate real numbers between 0 and 8 (8 included) and with a step size of 0.002 using the below command

```
import numpy as np
t=np.arange(0,8.002,0.002)
print(len(t))
print(t)
```

It should give the numbers from 0 to 8, where each number exceeds the previous number by a step size of 0.002. But it is also giving the last number 8.002 which should not be the case.

Output

```
4002
[0.000e+00 2.000e-03 4.000e-03 ... 7.998e+00 8.000e+00 8.002e+00]
```

But if I generate numbers between 0 and 7 with a step size of 0.002, then np.arange gives fine results

```
import numpy as np
t=np.arange(0,7.002,0.002)
print(len(t))
print(t)
```

Output

```
3501
[0.000e+00 2.000e-03 4.000e-03 ... 6.996e+00 6.998e+00 7.000e+00]
```

Can somebody tell how can I eliminate that last value 8.002 when generating numbers between 0 and 8 and why is this odd behaviour happening ??

Comment: From [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html?highlight=arange): When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use numpy.linspace for these cases.

Comment: I have no idea about why the problem is occuring but a way to fix it is to change the boundaries to 0,8.001 : `t=np.arange(0,8.001,0.002)` and it work as expected for both cases

Comment: Also I noticed that for 8.002 you get 4002 values, which is 8.002 // 0.002 + 1; with 7.002 you get 3501 values, which is 7.002 // 0.002 + 1. Might be a coincidence, but i guess there is a pattern. My guess is that arange falls back to linspace when using non integer steps, with `num=(end-start) // step + 1`, but it's just a guess, might be wildly wrong

Comment: @ Jules Civel, yaa your approach is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Use Numpy Linspace instead

You're running into a know problem. From the numpy arrange documentation :

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use numpy.linspace for these cases.

So instead use

```
start= 0
stop= 8
stepsize= 0.002
stepcount = int(round((stop-start)/stepsize))
t=np.linspace(start,stop,stepcount)
print(len(t))
print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

As said above you could use linspace or you could add the line below to your code, it will just remove the last element.

```py
t.pop()
```